# Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(a)[B -> B -> B]:

Tags: node.js, angular, stripe-payments

So, I am creating a job app in which people can search jobs. I am using Angular as frontend and NodeJS as backend. I am also using stripe to integrate payments and thus getting the same error again and again. I changed my code many times but I was getting the same error.

This is the following code of my backend:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));

const stripe = require("stripe")("confidential");

app.post("/checkout", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      shipping_address_collection: {
        allowed_countries: ["IN"],
      },
      line_items: req.body.items.map((amount) => ({
        price_data: {
          currency: "inr",
          product_data: {
            name: "Contribution",
            images: [],
          },
          unit_amount: amount * 100,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      })),
      mode: "payment",
      success_url: "http://localhost:4242/success.html",
      cancel_url: "http://localhost:4242/cancel.html",
    });

    res.status(200).json(session);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log("app is running on 4242"));
```

This is the code of my Angular component in  the frontend:

```
import {
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  OnInit,
  OnDestroy
} from '@angular/core';
import { Job } from './Job';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-job',
  templateUrl: './job.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./job.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class JobComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  jobs!: Job[];

  constructor(public changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.jobs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jobs') ?? '[]');
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  /**
 * This function fetches jobs from an API and stores them in local storage.
 * @param text The search query to filter jobs.
 * @param changeDetectorRef The ChangeDetectorRef object to detect changes and update the UI.
 */
  async fetchJobs(text: string): Promise<void> {
    const url = `https://jsearch.p.rapidapi.com/search?query=${text}&page=1&num_pages=1`;
    const options = {
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '5cf3ab5104msh8b2dc4fbca796c7p15d31ejsn73261ac3aeba',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'jsearch.p.rapidapi.com'
      }
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const data = await response.json();
      const jobs = data.data.map(({ job_title, job_description, job_google_link }: Job) => ({
        job_title,
        job_description,
        job_google_link
      }));
      localStorage.setItem('jobs', JSON.stringify(jobs));
      this.ngOnInit();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  }

  number(string: string): number {
    return Number.parseInt(string)
  }

  onContribute(amount: number): void {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:4242/checkout', {
      amount: amount
    }).subscribe(async (res: any) => {
      let stripe = await loadStripe('Confidential');
      stripe?.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: res.id
      })
    })
  }

}
```

This is the error:

```
ROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(a)[B -> B -> B]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for B!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(a)[B -> B -> B]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for B!
    at Ud.get (core.mjs:7599:27)
    at zd.get (core.mjs:8020:33)
    at zd.get (core.mjs:8020:33)
    at zd.get (core.mjs:8020:33)
    at Yy.get (core.mjs:12179:36)
    at Mi (core.mjs:3255:39)
    at Jo (core.mjs:3300:12)
    at Object.ys (core.mjs:10135:12)
    at f.ɵfac [as factory] (job.component.ts:19:26)
    at So (core.mjs:3485:44)
    at Ne (zone.js:1214:31)
    at Ne (zone.js:1168:17)
    at zone.js:1281:17
    at U.invokeTask (zone.js:409:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:24300:33)
    at U.invokeTask (zone.js:408:60)
    at D.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
    at C (zone.js:588:35)
    at I.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:494:21)
    at ae (zone.js:1664:18)
h
```

Comment: Can you share a complete stacktrace? and more context about the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah yes! I found the answer. I made a new module file for my job component and inserted the following code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JobComponent } from './job.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
})
export class JobModule { }
```

The following code imports everything form `HttpClientModule` and helps the job component to use it.